# Get "raw" content of screenshot in capybara, without saving image to disk

Tags: ruby, capybara

Is there a way to get the "raw" string content of an image when doing `session.driver.render('test.png')` in capybara, without actually saving the image to the disk and loading it back into memory afterwards?

Comment: what driver are you using? selenium, webkit, phantomjs? or is every driver possible for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS provides a `renderBase64` method. [API Reference](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference)

Poltergeist however provides no binding for it.
I just had a quick look, but I think you should be able to fork/patch Poltergeist to include the binding in [driver.rb](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb) and [browser.rb](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb)

Here is already a discussion about this: https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/189